# python - print unicode with comma

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why this

```
for name in session.query(Device.manufacturer_name):
    print name
```

results in

```
(u'Apple',)
(u'Samsung',)
(u'Sony',)
(u'HTC',)
```

but this - which I would think does exactly the same thing

```
for device in session.query(Device):
        print device.manufacturer_name
```

gives different result?

```
Apple
Samsung
Sony
HTC
```

Comment: Those are **tuples**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a specific column, and you get results in the form of rows. Each row is a tuple of just 1 value.

You can get that one value simply by indexing:

```
for row in session.query(Device.manufacturer_name):
    print row[0]
```

or you can use tuple assignment:

```
for name, in session.query(Device.manufacturer_name):
    print name
```

Note the comma in the `for` target list; Python now unpacks each tuple into the 'list' of one target name.

Answer (score 1):

They're tuples (likely [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)), you can unpack them like this:

```
for name, in session.query(Device.manufacturer_name):
    print name
```